# Chrome browser errors on refresh of grunt serve in angular web app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, bower

I'm working on a single page angularjs app and im using grunt and bower as a dev server and dependency injection respectively.  My application runs fine when it is first loaded from the "grunt serve" command, but when I refresh the page I get a string of uncaught type and reference errors and the application fails to load:

Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
jquery-ui.js:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined$.ui @ jquery-ui.js:14(anonymous function) @ jquery-ui.js:16
(index):1 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
bootstrap.js:8 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.js:8
angular-animate.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noop' of undefined(anonymous function) @ angular-animate.js:9(anonymous function) @ angular-animate.js:3721
angular-cookies.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined(anonymous function) @ angular-cookies.js:24(anonymous function) @ angular-cookies.js:321
angular-resource.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$minErr' of undefined(anonymous function) @ angular-resource.js:8(anonymous function) @ angular-resource.js:669
angular-route.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:24(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:992
angular-touch.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined(anonymous function) @ angular-touch.js:28(anonymous function) @ angular-touch.js:628
angular-chart.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not definedChart.defaults.global.responsive @ angular-chart.js:11(anonymous function) @ angular-chart.js:13
angular-aria.js:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined(anonymous function) @ angular-aria.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-aria.js:393
angular-material.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined(anonymous function) @ angular-material.js:13(anonymous function) @ angular-material.js:14(anonymous function) @ angular-material.js:17168
angular-sanitize.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$minErr' of undefined(anonymous function) @ angular-sanitize.js:19(anonymous function) @ angular-sanitize.js:683
(index):1 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
jquery.maskedinput.js:259 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) @ jquery.maskedinput.js:259
app.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(anonymous function) @ app.js:11
admin.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(anonymous function) @ admin.js:10
deployment.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(anonymous function) @ deployment.js:10
home.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(anonymous function) @ home.js:10
metrics.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(anonymous function) @ metrics.js:10
monitoring.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(anonymous function) @ monitoring.js:10
reporting.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(anonymous function) @ reporting.js:10
support.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(anonymous function) @ support.js:13
support.service.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(anonymous function) @ support.service.js:2
metrics.service.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(anonymous function) @ metrics.service.js:2
monitoring.service.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(anonymous function) @ monitoring.service.js:2
(index):1 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Has anyone experienced this before or know a solution?  I dont think its a problem with the code.

Answer (score 0):

For the "Maximum call stack size exceeded" you might want to check this: http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#why-am-i-getting-a-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error